# React.js: The value from variable was changed after checkbox but not written in <imput value={...}.../>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

One of the form fields: address Actual and address of registration. With an active checkbox, the address Actual should be equal to the address of registration. But in fact, the address Actual is not recorded in a variable.
When checkbox is active, call checkBoxAddress:

```
    checkBoxAddress = () => {
        this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked});
    }
```

Then check the checkbox before return(...), and change the value of the variable:

```
        if (this.state.checked) {
            addressActual = passportAddress;
            console.log(addressActual) // There are true value, worked. But not in form value

        }
```

Form:

```
...
<div className="form-group col-md-12">
                                <input name="passportAddress" type="text" className="form-control"
                                       placeholder="Адрес прописки"
                                       value={passportAddress} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-check">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck"
                                       onChange={this.checkBoxAddress}
                                       defaultChecked={this.state.checked}/>
                                <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="gridCheck">
                                    Адрес прописки совпадает с почтовым
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-row">
                            <div className="form-group col-md-12">
                                <input name="addressActual" type="text" className="form-control"
                                       placeholder="Адрес почтовый"
                                       value={addressActual} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                            </div>
...
```

In the input field, the address is substituted, but not stored in the variable:

[image: addressActual=""]

pasportAddress="12345", addressActual=""

Comment: I would like to see your changeHandler implementation. Moreover, I would suggest you to keep the textbox values in the state of the component and in the changeHandler you update the state of those values. And the same thing you must do when you're checking for checked state and update the actualAddress' value state. Hope this helps! Feel free to ask for any clarification if required.

Comment: @Srishti, 
```    
changeHandler = (e) => {

        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})

    };
```

Comment: it's perfect! Now, try modifying `value={passportAddress}` to `value={this.state.passportAddress}` and the same for actualAddress. And also do 
`if (this.state.checked) {
            this.setState({addressActual: this.state.passportAddress}
}`

Comment: @Srishti I Modifed values and try to add "if..." to checkBoxAddress and to changeHandler, but now data is not updated in form and in variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    checkBoxAddress = () => {
        console.log(this.state.checked)
        this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})
        if (!this.state.checked) {
            this.setState({addressActual: this.state.passportAddress})
        }
    };
```

Now, it's worked.